# wget append unique\defined prefix

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I am using `wget` in order to download a single URL into the local storage with `--no-directories` switch. It works smoothly, though I would like to achieve the same for several URLs while downloading each of which to the same directory (I cannot have sub directories). In order to achieve it, the files must be named uniquely while preserving the linking to them (within the HTML, JS, etc. files).

Is it possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

The command line switch `-k` can convert/rewite links but it will preserve the directory hierarchy.

So what you will need to do is download everything with a single `wget` command to convert the paths to local ones. In a second step, you can use `find` to get all file names, rename then and write a `sed` script which replaces the old with the new names in the HTML file.

Comment: Firstly, thanks you for your reply. I use the command `wget -E -H -k -K -p -nd -P myDir -T120 -t3 site.com`, which works great. Could you please refer me to `sed` since I will have to use it to modify the HTML files to refer to corresponding JS, CSS, etc. files. Any example will be extra great!

Comment: Please ask a new question for that :-)